# Get Text String from Doc Body and preserve line breaks

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I have a Google Doc which has the following in the document:

> ```
> Hello
> Replace me
> Line 2
> ```

I am trying to replace "Replace me" including the line break, with "I am replaced\nwith 2 lines" to make the final Doc contents equal:

> ```
> Hello
> I am replaced
> with 2 linesLine 2
> ```

My code is simply:

```
function myFunction() {
  var searchString = 'Replace me\n';
  var newString = 'I am replaced\nwith 2 lines';
  var stringData = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody();
  stringData.replaceText(searchString, newString);
}
```

I have tried changing searchString to use `\\n`, `\v`, `<br>`, `<br/>`, and maybe a few other items.

What do I need the searchString to contain to also include the line break?

Here is the [sample file with script](https://docs.google.com/document/d/17kT-Pd3RgQllcyWps17xRvikZJNOXPGavipZ6tghUeY/edit)

Answer (score 0):

```
function myFunction() {
  var searchStringNoLineBreak = 'Replace me';
  var searchStringRegex = "Replace me\\v";
  var substring = "I am replaced\nwith 2 lines";

  var body = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody();

  // get all paragraphs
  var paragraphs = body.getParagraphs();

  // loop paragraphs
  for (var i = 0; i < paragraphs.length; i++)
  {
    // current paragraph
    var p = paragraphs[i];

    // if found text with soft return, replace it
    if (p.findText(searchStringRegex))
    {
      p.replaceText(searchStringRegex, substring);
    }

    var isAtTheEnd = p.findText(searchStringNoLineBreak);

    // if text without newline was found but at the end of paragraph, we need to replace it too
    if (isAtTheEnd)
    {
      // replace text without new line character
      p.replaceText(searchStringNoLineBreak, substring);

      // then merge next paragraph with current to remove that new line between them
      if (i+1 < paragraphs.length)
      {
        var nextP = paragraphs[i+1];
        nextP.merge();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Input:

[image]

Result:

[image]

Comment: That does not put "Line 2" directly behind "with 2 lines" and only works when I we are not trying to Search for the line break.  In that case I can use single quotes as well.  The problem is searching for a string which includes the line break.

Comment: I have added code to search for a string with a line break.

Comment: I will try this. In my final product I will need to test for a line break and branch. Ultimately I will be looking for any text between `#[` and `]#` replacing portions of that with other values while preserving line breaks between these "tags." So in my still simplified sample text I would search the document for "#[Replace me\n]#" replacing it with "I am replaced\nwith 2 lines" after first looking to see if there is a line break in the text read. I know there is a "\n" which the debugger does not show in the read text. I was just hoping for a more simplified method using the replaceText().